# Variable Substitution

Tags: bash, variables, sh, freebsd

Having an issue in FreeBSD 8.3 using an SH shell script.

The following date command works in FreeBSD

```
date -j -f "%Y/%m/%d" "$ii" '+%s'
```

The script needs to run in both FreeBSD and Ubuntu, but the date function above does not work in Ubuntu.

This works in Ubuntu

```
date --date="$ii" +"%s"
```

So I want to have a variable to switch between these two depending on the OS.

```
# Options (freebsd/linux)
recdate=freebsd

ii=2014/06/06

if [ "$recdate" == "freebsd" ]; then
   recdate="\`date \-j \-f \"\%Y/\%m/\%d\" \"\$ii\" \'\+\%s\'\`"
else
   recdate="\`date \-\-date\=\"\$ii\" \+\"\%s\"\`"
fi
```

I have tried multiple escaping and quoting without success.

The error is as follows (using set -x):

```
+ [ '' == freebsd ]
+ date --date= +%s
date: illegal option -- -
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
       [-f fmt date | [[[[[cc]yy]mm]dd]HH]MM[.ss]] [+format]
+ recdate=''
```

Comment: Did `+ [ '' == freebsd ]` give you a hint?

Comment: This is the trouble with using non-standard extensions; you get non-standardized behaviour.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @devnull points out in a comment, **your OS test fails, because your `$recdate` variable is actually empty**, as evidenced by the  `+ [ '' == freebsd ]` output line after applying `set -x`.

Another thing to note is that you're combining `[ ... ]` (POSIX syntax) with `==` (`bash` syntax).
**Use `=` with `[ ... ]`**: `[ "$recdate" = "freebsd" ]`

As for detecting FreeBSD, I suggest you do:

```
if [ "$(uname)" = "FreeBSD" ]; then ....
```

Or, if you want to set a flag:

```
[ "$(uname)" = "FreeBSD" ] && isFreeBSD=1 || isFreeBSD=

# ...

if [ $isFreeBSD ]; then # ....
```

---

Finally, the way you construct your `date` command is awkward.

I suggest you create a shell function that encapsulates the differences between the two platforms:

```
# Shell function that encapsulates differences between FreeBSD and Linux.
toEpochTime() {
  if [ "$(uname)" = "FreeBSD" ]; then
    date -j -f "%Y/%m/%d" "$1" '+%s'
  else
    date --date="$1" +"%s"
  fi
}

# Invoke the function 
toEpochTime '2014/06/06'
```

---

**Afterthought**:

@chepner points out in a comment that it's inefficient to execute the conditional that determines the host OS every time the function is invoked.

He suggests using the conditional *once* to *define the function platform-specifically* (note that while other languages might balk at defining a function with the same name twice, in different branches of an `if` statement, `bash` allows it):

```
# Define helper function `toEpochTime()` in a platform-dependent
# manner, based on the output of `uname`:
if [ "$(uname)" = 'FreeBSD' ]; then
  toEpochTime() { date -j -f "%Y/%m/%d" "$1" '+%s'; }
else   
  toEpochTime() { date --date="$1" +"%s"; }
fi

# Invoke the function.
toEpochTime '2014/06/06'
```

Comment: I use a similar format for the whole script and this is the only instance where it fails. I still would like to find the issue why it doesn't work. But I agree that this is the best option overall!

Comment: @CA171: Have you tried with a _single_ `=` in the conditional, as suggested: `[ "$recdate" = "freebsd" ]`? What shell is interpreting this? What does `set -x` show after you assign to `recdate`?

Comment: I copied my script to a test folder and I missed changing a path variable. So it was looking at the previous folder. Sorry! I tried my original format and it now outputs                                    + [ '' == freebsd ]
+ recdate='`date \-\-date\="$ii" \+"\%s"`'  I will try the other suggestions also.

Comment: One suggestion: instead of putting the conditional inside the function, use the conditional to define one wrapper or another. It saves having to call `uname` every time you call `toEpochTime`, and it would make the output of something like `type toEpochTime` be shorter and machine-specific.